# How to send firmware package from LWM2M Leshan server to LWM2M Wakaama client?

Tags: iot, coap, lwm2m

I have a LwM2M Wakaama client working with a Leshan server. When I try to send a huge hexbinary string via the write option on Package resource for Firmware update object 5, I get the following error message on the client side:

> "Block1 NOT IMPLEMENTED".

I understand that block1 was not implemented on the wakaama client and only block2 was implemented, does anyone know why?

Also, How can I make firmware update with package resource work with the Leshan Server and Wakaama Client?

I believe I can either change the Leshan Server to send a request of type BLOCK2 (which I dont know how to do from the limited UI?) or add support for BLOCK1 on Wakaama LWM2M client.

Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Block1 support by doing the following changes in the function lwm2m_handle_packet in Paket.c ~ line 234-263:

```
       /* get offset for blockwise transfers */
        if (coap_get_header_block2(message, &block_num, NULL, &block_size, &block_offset))
        {
            LOG("Blockwise2: block request %u (%u/%u) @ %u bytes\n", block_num, block_size, REST_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, block_offset);
            block_size = MIN(block_size, REST_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);
            new_offset = block_offset;
        }
        ++else if (coap_get_header_block1(message, &block_num, NULL, &block_size, &block_offset))
        ++{
            ++LOG("Blockwise1: block request %u (%u/%u) @ %u bytes\n", block_num, block_size, REST_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE, block_offset);
            ++block_size = MIN(block_size, REST_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE);
            ++new_offset = block_offset;
        ++}
        coap_error_code = handle_request(contextP, fromSessionH, message, response);
        if (coap_error_code==NO_ERROR)
        {
            /* Apply blockwise transfers. */
            if ( IS_OPTION(message, COAP_OPTION_BLOCK1) && response->code<BAD_REQUEST_4_00 && !IS_OPTION(response, COAP_OPTION_BLOCK1) )
            {
                ++//LOG("Block1 NOT IMPLEMENTED\n");

                ++//coap_error_code = NOT_IMPLEMENTED_5_01;
                ++//coap_error_message = "NoBlock1Support";
                ++LOG("Block1 IMPLEMENTED\n");
                ++coap_set_header_block1(response, block_num, 0, block_size);

            }
            else if ( IS_OPTION(message, COAP_OPTION_BLOCK2) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the version of wakaama you use is up-to-date? the last master is supposed to support block transfer

Comment: Yes its the latest version. The problem seems to be in the functions lwm2m_handle_packet in [Paket.c](https://github.com/eclipse/wakaama/blob/master/core/packet.c) ~ line 245. `if ( IS_OPTION(message, COAP_OPTION_BLOCK1) && response->code<BAD_REQUEST_4_00 && !IS_OPTION(response, COAP_OPTION_BLOCK1) )
                {
                    LOG("Block1 NOT IMPLEMENTED\n");
... .  `  I could see there is some implementation for BLOCK2 payload, but I dont have a way to specift that in the Leshan server UI.